# How can I turn off (disable, negate) an rspec command line option?

Tags: command-line, rspec, arguments, suppress

In my team's Rails app, our file `.rspec` includes `--profile`.

I don't want profile information showing up 99% of the times I run rspec locally. Changing `.rspec` for the whole team is not an option.

In my file `.rspec-local` (which is gitignored), I would like to suppress or override the setting in `.rspec`

Is this possible?

What is the syntax to do suppress an rspec parameter already declared?

Answer (score 1):

Prefix flag options with `no-` to override previous declarations. For example, `.rspec` gets loaded first, then `.rspec-local` gets loaded second:

.rspec:

```
--profile
--no-color
```

.rspec-local:

```
--no-profile
--color
```

The result is that rspec will run without the profile, and with color.

EDIT: TIL that you can create ~/.rspec in your home directory and it will be loaded for all your projects!   Unfortunately, that doesn't work when your tests run inside a docker container.

Comment: What if you want to override a `--require` option?